# Equivalent to DataJpaTest for Spring Data's ReactiveCrudRepository and R2DBC

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

For [`JpaRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) there is [`@DataJpaTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html). `@DataJpaTest` allows for simple and isolated testing of JPA repositories in Spring.

We are using [`spring-data-r2dbc`](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-r2dbc). Is there an equivalent of `@DataJpaTest` for [`ReactiveCrudRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/reactive/ReactiveCrudRepository.html) to test it in isolation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, as of Spring Boot 2.3 you can use [`@DataR2dbcTest`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/data/r2dbc/DataR2dbcTest.java) to spin up a context for your R2DBC repositories (including the `DatabaseClient`):

```
@DataR2dbcTest
class DataR2dbcTestIntegrationTests {

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseClient databaseClient;

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @Test
    void testDatabaseClient() {
        this.databaseClient.execute("SELECT * FROM example").fetch().all()
             .as(StepVerifier::create).verifyComplete();
    }

    // …
}
```

Comment: Will @DataR2dbcTest take care of rolling back changes after running other test?

Comment: No, because `@Test` methods are not participating in transaction management.